Problems with character with "Stretch to" when exported as FBX
I'm working on a humanoid slime character, then his animations are super soft and stretched, then I use the "Stretch to" Constraint, but when I export it as FBX, the entire mesh distorts, but in Blender it remains normal, only if you import it FBX is distorted in Blender, what could it be? please help me, this model is urgent

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Xm1h700uhk your problem is examinated at around min 41.00.

Hello and welcome to BSE. Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com
